# Getting item id after inserting with Javascript Client OM

Tags: client-object-model

Is it possible to get the inserted item id after executeQueryAsync? Or do I have to send a second query to get the item id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to fire a second query.

Comment: That's really ridiculous. So I have to put a unique value while saving the item because I have to find the exact item I saved.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there might be a way. See this post on the MSDN forums:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/d9c68caa-ddfd-4a68-a32f-d6154546f42e

It is using the Silverlight Client Object Model but there should be something similar in the ECMA Script too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Elodie have you see this post
[Use SPServices.SPRedirectWithID in a custom new form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15800/use-spservices-spredirectwithid-in-a-custom-new-form)
Maybe it can give you an idea
Cheers